# A decent stereo pair of microphones at a reasonable price?

Tags: microphone, recording, instruments, stereo

Hello. I'm curious to know what people are using as a stereo pair of microphones for their recordings? I've been looking at the usual suspects, but was curious to know if there is any underdogs in the microphone world that are reasonably priced but do a good job?

Ideally, I'm wanting to record not only foley sounds, but sounds for me to mangle further, for recording instruments like piano and acoustic guitar etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with Rode NT-5s, and I think they're absolutely brilliant. I've recorded entire albums with them, they're super flexible and sound great on guitar and piano and pretty much everything else (although vocals are a bit of a stretch). Very cheap too!

Comment: the stereo røde nt4 mic uses two nt5 capsules. it can be powered by 9V battery. the 3.5mm stereo plug that comes with it apparently has a built-in -12dB pad, but it can be bypassed (confirmed by røde) http://bit.ly/9inpaz

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I don't really like the nt4 that much! I know it uses the same capsules, but I think I liked the flexibility of having the two separate mics, and I'm not a big fan of XY stereo recording anyway.

Answer (score 2):

anyone know anything about Avantone microphones?...more specificaly the Avantone CK-40....seems like a nice stereo mic....seems like it has some of the features of Neumann RSM-191...for a fraction of the price...

Answer (score 1):

i would go for AKG c451's. they are really great as over mics for drums and whatever else i have recorded on them. also i have heard really good words about m-audio's pulsars as a cheaper choise

Comment: I would look for an older pair of the AKG's. The new ones with the digital switches seem s noisy to me. I also don't like having to make an extra trip to the mic to set the switches after I've engaged phantom. It's minor, but irritating. 

Answer (score 1):

I often use paired [Oktava MK-012](http://www.oktava-online.com/mk012.htm), for shorts movies, documentary and a lot of stuff. Interior + exterior. Very good russian microphones. [Here](http://recordinghacks.com/2008/07/17/oktava-mk012-capsules/) is a review.